# How can the 3M22 Zircon receive commands at high speeds?

Tags: radio-communications, scramjet

According to [its Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M22_Zircon), the scramjet-powered 3M22 Zircon missile is capable of achieving speeds of up to Mach 9, at which a plasma may be created around the missile. The article further mentions a [plasma stealth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_stealth) effect "absorbing any radio waves" but then goes on to say it "exchanges information in flight and can be controlled by commands". If the plasma cloud around it absorbs all radio waves, then how can it still receive commands?

Comment: Educated guess from someone not involved in plasma physics or radio technology: most likely communication with the missile happens on a part of the spectrum that penetrates plasma better, but is probably less conventional in radio communication.